# C# - why is my countdown timer not working?

Tags: c#, timer, monogame

Am I missing something? I've got my timer:

```
private int timer = 10;
```

And in my Update class, I have it so that when the timer reaches 0, an object will move across the X-axis.

```
do { timer--; }
while (timer > 0);

if (timer == 0)
{
    object1X--;
}
```

When I hit run, absolutely nothing happens. I've tried changing the timer to 0, and still nothing. I have a fair amount of C# knowledge, more than enough to know that this should work.
Maybe today is a brain-dead day and I'm missing something obvious... thank you in advance :)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] rather than just tiny snippets. Fundamentally though, your tight loop is just a complicated and inefficient way of saying `if (timer > 0) { timer = 0; }`.

Comment: @JonSkeet Not really, as it will decrement it once regardless.

Comment: Because the `if` is not inside the loop. Write `while (timer > 0) { DoSomething();  timer--; }`. Also it will take only nanoseconds for the timer to count down. Insert a `Thread.Sleep(waitTimeInMilliseconds);` in the loop.

Comment: seems to me as it is doing something: https://dotnetfiddle.net/X9rzd7

Comment: @GSerg: Ah, true. Other than that "decrement once if non-positive" aspect (which probably isn't desirable anyway), it's still just an inefficient approach...

Comment: `if (timer == 0)` is not necessary, as `timer` will always be `0` after the loop has been processed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The do-while statement runs the code inside the brackets before checking the condition. On the first iteration of the code, the while loop decreases the timer to 0, as expected, and then evaluates the logical expression in the if statement. Since it will be true, it will run your if statement once.

However, on the second iteration, the code will decrement your timer again (from 0 to -1), and then stop decrementing it, since it is not greater than 0. Then, when your if statement runs, it evaluates the expression as false, because -1 != 0. It will continue decrementing the timer variable, but since 0 is greater than all negative numbers, it will never return to 0, and the logical expression in your if statement will never evaluate to true again.

Comment: thank you 256Bits, this explained my problem perfectly! :)

Answer (score 4):

I'll take it for granted the `Draw()` method is properly using the `object1X` value. With that in mind, there are four issues here.

First, the timer loop is *NOT* just running one iteration per Update() call. It runs to completion the first time, and this takes at most a few ***micro***seconds... much less than one video frame. This happens so fast you'd never even have a chance to register the initial value relative to the final value.

Second, the `object1X--;` code inside the `if()` block is **outside** and **after** the timer loop, such that the entire loop runs to completion on the first Update() call before ever changing `object1X`.

Third, because this is a pre-fix (`do`) loop, the `timer--` statement will continue to execute once on subsequent `Update()` calls and continue into negative values, even though it already reached 0 after the first Update(). This means the `if (timer == 0)` conditional check will not succeed on those later updates.

Finally, the item only moves one pixel. You'll have a hard time noticing this on a modern hi-res display.

---

The main fix here is removing the loop completely, so the normal Update() mechanism can handle decrementing the value. Separate from this, you may want to add an actual time or frame check, since you don't know for sure how often Update() is called.

Answer (score 0):

In the code you've written, unless everything is in a loop, your code will only execute once, and based on how much 1 is for your `object1X` variable, this change could be a 1-pixel change, which wouldn't be noticeable if you're working on a large display.

Instead, you could try to have a timer, where every timer tick would move the object. Here I've used a `PeriodicTimer`:

```cs
TimeSpan tickDelay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
PeriodicTimer timer = new PeriodicTimer(tickDelay);

while (await timer.WaitForNextTickAsync())
{
    object1X--;
}
```

Firstly, I create my `PeriodicTimer` object and give it 10 seconds between every tick, after which I define a loop that will only execute every tick (every 10 seconds) and will decrease the `object1X` value.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

the final code I've ended up with is as follows:

```
private int object1X = 100;
private int timer = 200;

protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    if(timer > 0)
    {
        timer--;
    }
    if(timer == 0)
    {
        object1X--;
    {
}
```

This moves the object across the screen - after the timer has hit 0 - with no problems.
I could use `TimeSpan` and `PeriodicTimer` (as suggested by Borisonekenobi in another answer) but because my program is quite a small one, I personally think `if` statements will work best :)